# Almost sure convergence clarification

Tags: probability, measure-theory

Let $\Omega=(0,1]$, $\mathbb{P}$ be Lebesgue measure, $n\in\mathbb{N}$ be $n = i + 2^j$, where $j = \lfloor\log_2(n)\rfloor$ and $0 \leq i \lt 2^j$.

Let's say I have a random variable $X_n(\omega)=\mathbb{I}_\left(\frac{i}{2^j},\frac{i+1}{2^j}\right]$ or even $X_n(\omega)=n^p \mathbb{I}_\left(\frac{i}{2^j},\frac{i+1}{2^j}\right]$, for $p>0$ and $\mathbb{I}_S$ an indicator function that is $1$ if $\omega\in S$ and $0$ otherwise. I understand that almost sure convergence (to zero) fails because e.g. in the second case, $\forall\omega\in\Omega$, there is some interval among the $2^j$ intervals for which $X_n(\omega)=n^p$. In fact, this occurs infinitely often. Therefore the set $\{\omega: X_n(\omega)\to 0\}$ is empty.

My question is does this hold true for $X_n(\omega)=\frac{1}{n^p} \mathbb{I}_\left(\frac{i}{2^j},\frac{i+1}{2^j}\right]$, for $p>0$. My guess is that this does converge to zero almost surely because I can get $X_n$ close enough to zero  (within $\epsilon>0$) with probability $1$. I'm not sure if this is rigorous enough and would like additional insight if I'm on the right track. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost sure convergence is pointwise convergence almost everywhere.
$$0\le X_n(\omega)=\frac{1}{n^p} \mathbb{I}_\left(\frac{i}{2^j},\frac{i+1}{2^j}\right](\omega)\le\frac1{n^p}.$$
By the squeeze theorem, $X_n$ converges to zero in *every* point.